# Is there any way to break if operator like as while

Tags: php, if-statement

Is there any way to break an `if` statement like a `while` loop?

```
while(true) { 
    break;
}

if(true) {
    //break if
} else {
    //continue execution here or miss if at all
}
```

Comment: did you search for **continue;**?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want execution to jump to the start of the `else` block? You could always use a [`goto`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) (and note that `break` and `continue` are just specialized forms of `goto`), but 99% of the time, there's a better way.

Comment: @donald123 `continue` isn't meaningful inside an `if`

Comment: there are no reason to do this... if your if is finish, just close it. you can use goto perhaps, but it is not recommanded.

Comment: PHP is prozedural, you cannot jump back into the loop aber it is finished.

Comment: Please remove the comments regarding `goto`, we should definitely not recommend using it ...

Comment: That's kinda xy problem. Why do you decide to break an `if`? What's the reason for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using `goto`. Use with caution, as it's usually an indication of bad code habits elsewhere. It does have legitimate uses though (like breaking out of nested loops).

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

I think your question is poorly-worded. I think this is the problem you're having:

```
if( foo ) {
    if( bar ) {
        baz();
    } else {
        qux();
    }
} else {
    qux();
}
```

You want to simplify this so that `qux()` need only be expressed once, rather than twice. A possible solution using `goto` exists:

```
if( foo ) {
    if( bar ) {
        baz();
    } else {
        goto quxLabel;
    }
} else {
    quxLabel:
    qux();
}
```

This works, but I think a better solution (if possible in your case) is to compose your branch conditions. This requires that you be able to evaluate `bar` independently of `foo`, so I don't know if this applies in your case:

```
if( foo && bar ) baz();
else             qux();
```

If `bar` depends on `foo` then you can still use this technique, but take advantage of the short-circuiting behaviour of the `&&` operator:

```
if( foo && computeBar( foo ) ) baz();
else                           qux();
```

Comment: I know that use bookmarks is no good coding style but its maybe the single way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Simply, inverse the order and use `!`:

```
<?php
if(!true){
echo "execution here or miss if at all";
} else {
echo "Nothing";
}
```

View this DEMO: http://codepad.org/XdFKfY9R

Answer (score 0):

The `if`-statement is used to branch code without repetition so there is no need for a `break` constructor. It's a different thing when you are using `loop` control statements, especially those without a given loop condition statement like:

```
while (1==1) {
  ...
}
```

To avoid endless loops you will need to combine branch and loop statements, perhaps that was the idea behind your question:

```
 while (1==1) {

   // do stuff
   ...

   // special condition
   if ($cancel) {
     break;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  if(true){ 
   goto end; 
  }
  else {
  continue execution here or miss if at all
  }  
  end:
  /* your statement*/
```

Comment: you want try exit() function

Comment: `exit()` terminates _all_ future execution. That doesn't sound like what is being asked for.

Comment: Please *never* construct code like that otherwise you'll end up jumping around without structure.

Comment: It is the first time I see `goto` since Q-basic! :)

Comment: Most people consider use of `goto` to be harmful, and it will never appear in a well structured application. `return` and `exit` simply won't do what's being asked.

Answer (score -2):

```
try {
    if (...) {
        do_something();
        ...
        throw new \Exception(); // Break here
        ...
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {}

// Resumes here:
do_something_now()
```

Using Exceptions is generally the best way to break out of loops (or anything else). They are used to indicate an error, but can be caught and handled wherever you like.

Comment: This may be right in case an unhandled condition occurs, but it's not the usual case for exiting a loop structure.

Comment: No, but breaking out of conditionals isn't really a usual case heh. That said, if you're dealing with deeply nested loops (which itself is a code smell), using exceptions to handle flow control when something unexpected happens is probably the best way to do it (certainly superior than breaking multiple levels ie a `break 3;`).

Comment: You are right if we are talking about exiting a program while meeting an unexpected condition (like in your example) but this is not necessarily true about loop statements (i.e. imagine looping a collection until a specific element is found).

Comment: Why else would need to break out of an if conditional other than an unexpected condition? If the condition is expected wouldn't you just test for it in the conditional up front?